# Interactive user input while using stdout

Tags: python

in a script I use `sys.stdout.write()` to output processed data to stdout, which later I use on CLI to redirect stdout to file:

```
python.exe script.py > file.out
```

I could not write to file inside python script as redirected file can't be known

My problem is that I use also `raw_input()`, as I need user to pass certain number before processing starts, but prompt doesn't show as I redirect stdout - i.e. script waits for user input but does not show anything

Can someone give me a tip how to handle this?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the filename as a command-line argument instead of redirecting stdout. That way, you can print output or use `raw_input()` as normal. Example:

```
import sys

outfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'w')
# write to the outfile
x = raw_input("What's your name?")
outfile.write(x)
```

Usage:

```
python myscript.py file.out
```

This will work on any platform.

Comment: I want to print to stdout by default. I can check if there is argument after the script, and if there isn't then write to stdout instead to file, but I was seeking for a way without writing to file from this script if possible. Thanks

Comment: @Ghostly why? What's wrong with writing to a file (especially stdout)? That's no different from a plain `print`.

Comment: OK, maybe you are right. I have couple of interacting scripts, and defaulting to stdout was desired in this examples. I'll check if there is argument - if so write to file, and if not I'll use stdout. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
# Disable buffering for stdout
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
x = raw_input(">")
print x
```

Run this as:

```
python ./test.py | tee ./file.out
```

Now, you will see your output on console and it will be redirected to the file.out as well.

Comment: you should add that in windows you must install the tee program.